# Why does my input form not send data to my SQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms, user-input

I am trying to send input data to an SQL database, but it doesn't work. Database name is scifair and table name (within database) is users. The issue resides in these two php files. I am using phpmyadmin to manage the SQL database. Please tell me what I need to fix as soon as possible!

add.php

```
<?php

include_once 'includes/db_connect.php';

$firstname = $email = '';
    $errors = array('firstname'=>'', 'email'=>'');

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    // check name
    if(empty($_POST['firstname'])){
        $errors['firstname'] = 'Enter a name! <br />';
    } else {
        echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['firstname']);
        $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
        if(!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z]+$/', $firstname)){
            $errors['firstname'] = 'Name can only be letters! <br />';
        }
    }
    // check email
    if(empty($_POST['email'])){
        $errors['email'] = 'Enter an email! <br />';
    } else {        
        echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']);
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
            $errors['email'] = 'Invalid email! <br />';
        }
    }

    if(array_filter($errors)){
        echo ' errors in the form';
    } else {
        echo ' form is valid';
    }
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>SCIENCE FAIR</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <section class ="container grey-text">
    <form class="white" action="add.php" method="POST">
    <tr>
        <label>First Name:</label>
        <td><input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name"></td></br>
        <?php echo $errors['firstname']; ?></div>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <label>Email:</label>
        <td><input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email"></td></br>
        <?php echo $errors['email']; ?></div>
    </tr>
        <div class="center">
            <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></td>
        </div>
    </form>

</section>
</html>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    $query = "INSERT INTO users (name, email) VALUES ($firstname, $email)";
    mysqli_query($conn, $query);
}
?>
```

db_connect.php

```
<?php

$dbServername = "localhost";
$dbUsername = "scifair";
$dbPassword = "password";
$dbName = "scifair";
// connect to database
$conn = mysqli_connect($dbServername, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);

// check connection
if(!$conn){
    echo 'Connection error: ' . mysqli_connect_error();
}
?>
```

Comment: What is the error that display?

Comment: Use parameterized queries.

Comment: Use quotes around string values that you are inserting to database - `"INSERT INTO users (name, email) VALUES ('$firstname', '$email')"`

Comment: Without more information, it is almost impossible to provide any kind of answer. What error are you getting (if any)? How is the result different from what you expect? Also, do not use the code suggested by Alex. It is wide open to SQL injection. Use parameterized queries instead as suggested by @stickybit.

Comment: @SloanThrasher, what SQL injection would be used in order to bypass the preg_match function or the FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL?

Comment: Quite a few, but the simplest would just involve using a quote character in a field or an open/close PHP symbol in the input. There a lot of tricks that could be used. The best way to avoid these kind of attacks is to use parameterized queries which will automatically quote the data, handle special characters, etc.

Comment: Again, edit your question to show what errors you see. Turn on error display in the PHP code to show any possible errors.

Comment: @SloanThrasher Also, wouldn't it be impossible for a user to enter quotes or any other symbols due to the preg_match function only allowing the user to insert letters?

Comment: @SloanThrasher Nvm, got it working again. I misspelled something in the table. But, would $firstname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['firstname']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO usersthree (name, email) VALUES (?, ?)";
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)){
        echo "SQL error!";
    } else {
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $firstname, $email);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    } be a valid prepared statement?

Comment: Maybe, but you should get into separating validation from execution. There are ways to get around your code that I won't share here because someone might try them. Take a look at [PHP Prepared Statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) for a simple but great look at prepared statement. For a more lengthy example, and good reasons to use them, take a look at [PHP: Mysqli Prepared Statements to prevent SQL injection](https://websitebeaver.com/prepared-statements-in-php-mysqli-to-prevent-sql-injection).

Comment: PS: If you plan on developing many PHP/MySQL projects, you can also look at using [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php), which is more readable, IMHO, and easier to maintain (again, IMHO). If you use either of these on a consistent basis, you can avoid SQL Injection issues in the future. One cool feature of using these is that if you need to execute the same statement repeatedly with different values in the variables, you don't need to redo the SQL statement. Just change the values, and execute the statement.

Comment: @SloanThrasher So is SQL injection possible in both an INSERT sql query and a SELECT sql query? I've tried SQL injecting the current input form (also removing the preg_match and filter_validate_email functions) with Y’; UPDATE users SET email = ‘abennepal@gmail.com’ WHERE email = ‘aben101@icloud.com’; and it doesn't work. Is this an issue with my SQL code, or does the INSERT need to be changed to a SELECT (in order to search the table instead of adding a new user to the table)?

Comment: It's possible with any SQL statement where you use data from a user form. With prepared statements, the data is transmitted separately and as data so it isn't interpreted or executed.